# What's the best way to accomplish receiving an stream and keep it going 247 but have a fail over solution?

Tags: ubuntu, streaming

I want to use a small Linux machine to receive an icecast stream from the internet and play out through a usb sound card. I can do this easy enough with several programs. The problem is that I want to be able to monitor that there is audio being played and if the stream goes down or the network goes down, then I want to play some files I keep on the machine automatically.

BUT! if the stream comes back online or the network issues are resolved, I'd like to automatically resume streaming.

I'm sure this can be done with a script of some sort but I'm kind of at a loss on where to start.

Comment: CloudRadio Monitor https://www.cloudrad.io/pricing/ , NodePing https://nodeping.com/pricing.htm , Qosifire https://qosifire.com/price/ , RadioMast https://www.radiomast.io/pricing/ , and StreamVerify http://www.streamverify.com/index.php/prices are either paid services or require paying for something else.  However, they will all message you when something goes awry, and that can trigger playing local music files while you look for the problem. Are you open to monthly charges?

Comment: I already have the stream server. I need the client.

Comment: You can buy just the monitoring service without changing your server.

Comment: I think I didn't explain what I needed correctly. I have the server and audio going to it, I need a device to play the stream locally and then if the stream is off line or something goes wrong, I want to play a set of predetermined audio files.

Comment: And, after looking for a local monitoring app, I struck out, so I asked if you were open to paying for the service.